# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, Windows partition is present but Windows bootloader doesn't start

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows, it never occured to me before but when I try to enter Windows from its bootloader it doesn't load, the partition remains present and I can access the files from Ubuntu.

The problem is that when on selection I try to enter Windows instead of Ubuntu, once selecting Windows bootloader it stops there black screen and doesn't do anything

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you cannot get it going, boot to USB, back up, reinstall Windows and use Virtual Machines. You will wind up wasting much (much) less time.

Comment: It might be relevant to know if your dual boot installs are in Legacy (MBR) Mode or UEFI (GPT) Mode.

Comment: How do I know that?